# Bad cast while getting data from PostgreSQL database using SOCI

Tags: c++, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, soci

I have a database in PostgreSQL. And I have sql query (which btw works great in PostgreSQL, **so the sql code isn't wrong**):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as size, creation_date FROM item INNER JOIN raf_item USING (id) INNER JOIN item_detail USING (id) GROUP BY creation_date;
```

where creation date is defined as `creation_date Date;` in PostgreSQL.The query returns, for example (depends on what I have in my database):

```
size | creation_date
21   | 12-31-2012
18   | 04-03-2002
```

I'm using SOCI + C++ to get data from this query. My whole C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <soci.h>
#include <string>
#include <postgresql/soci-postgresql.h>
using namespace std;

bool connectToDatabase(soci::session &sql, string databaseName, string user, string password)
{
    try
    {
        sql.open(soci::postgresql, "dbname=" +databaseName + " user="+user + " password="+password);
    }
    catch (soci::postgresql_soci_error const & e)
    {
        cerr << "PostgreSQL error: " << e.sqlstate() << " " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    catch (std::exception const & e)
    {
        cerr << "Some other error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void getDataFromDatabase(soci::session &sql)
{
    soci::row r;
    sql << "select count(*) as size, creation_date from item inner join raf_item using (id) inner join item_detail using (id) group by creation_date;", soci::into(r);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i != r.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << r.get<int>(i);
        tm when = r.get<tm>(i);
        cout << asctime(&when);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    soci::session sql;
    bool success = connectToDatabase(sql, "testdb", "testuser", "pass");
    if (success)
    {
        cout << "Connected.\n";
        getDataFromDatabase(sql);
    }

    else
        cout << "Not connected.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But I got this error, when I tried to run the application (compilation is fine) :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
>   what():  std::bad_cast Interrupt (core dumped)

Please help, when the compilation is fine I really don't know how to fix this.

**Maybe the problem is that creation_date is DATE and tm keeps also time ... ? If so, how to fix this?**

Comment: Have you tried running your executable in a debugger?

Comment: @cdhowie: Nope, I didn't - I don't know much about debugging unfortunately :/

Comment: This would probably be a good way to learn.

Comment: @cdhowie: I know you're right, I just thought that maybe someone had this issue with soci and could help ... I almost sure that the problem is with `creation_date` type ...

Comment: Well, what have you tried to confirm this?  Have you tried to write things to `cout` to verify exactly where the crash is occurring?  It looks like you received this crash and just gave up.  At least try to figure out which line is triggering the crash.

Comment: @cdhowie: I added try{}catch clause around the piece of code where I try to get data from the database - and that's it, the error is there ... Now, how to fix it?

Comment: @cdhowie: don't bother yourself anymore, the problem is solved:)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: ok, thank's I just did it:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you did solve your question, the code you posted is more a workaround than the real solution for the problem.

Your problem is, that COUNT(*) returns a value of bigint (or int8) type, as described [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html),
and soci converts bigint to a `long long int` type, as described [in this chart](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/backends/postgresql.html#support). If the types do not match excatly, a bad_cast exception will be thrown.

Therefore, the code in your question should be `cout << r.get<long long>(i);` to avoid the bad_cast exception.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I SOLVED IT BY MYSELF!:)

Heres the code that actualy works fine (I only repleced `getDataFromDatabase` with this code below):

```
void getDataFromDatabase(soci::session &sql)
{
    long size;
    string date;

    soci::row r;
    sql << "select count(*) as size, creation from item inner join raf_item using (id) inner join item_detail using (id) group by creation;", soci::into(r);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i != r.size(); ++i)
    {
        const soci::column_properties & props = r.get_properties(i);

    cout << '<' << props.get_name() << '>';

    switch(props.get_data_type())
    {
    case soci::dt_string:
        cout << r.get<std::string>(i);
        break;
    case soci::dt_double:
        cout << r.get<double>(i);
        break;
    case soci::dt_integer:
        cout << r.get<int>(i);
        break;
    case soci::dt_unsigned_long:
        cout << r.get<unsigned long>(i);
        break;
    case soci::dt_long_long:
        cout << r.get<long long>(i);
        size = r.get<long long>(i);
        break;
    case soci::dt_date:
        std::tm when = r.get<std::tm>(i);
        cout << asctime(&when);
        date = asctime(&when);
        break;
    }

    cout << "\n" << size << "\n";
    cout << "\n" << date << "\n";
}
```